# Soundex against individual values in CSV column

Tags: mysql, sql, soundex

I suspect this may not be doable, but I figured I'd try anyway.

In a MySQL database, one of the columns `related` is a comma-separated list of values: `bob,sally,james,rick`.

For a given row, the number of items in this column is variable.

Now, if I want to do a soundex search against all the items in that column (client request well after this db has been established and integrated), how would I go about this? I'd want to write something like

`` SELECT `primary` FROM `table` WHERE `related`.split(",").any() SOUNDS LIKE sample ``

Which is plainly nonsense code but hopefully conveys the idea.

Essentially, explode/split a CSV field into individual values to `SOUNDEX` compare. If I have to get all those `related` fields, explode them and then `soundex()` them individually in a PHP `foreach()` loop so be it (that language isn't really important, it could be Python, too, with just a touch more effort), but I'd love to avoid it if possible.

Comment: There are reasons why denormalized databases are hell to work with.  You've just found yet another one.

Comment: The beauty of roving targets on a WIP. The whole thing started with no databases at all, then the initial one didn't even have a concept of the data in `related`, and so forth ... I never thought I'd be so anxious to refactor all my code.